# decltype and lvalue expression

Tags: c++, c++11, lvalue, decltype

according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype

```
struct A {
    double x;
};
const A* a = new A();

decltype( a->x ) x3;
```

match 1 case, i.e:

*If the argument is either the unparenthesised name of an object/function, or is a member access expression (object.member or pointer->member), then the `decltype` specifies the declared type of the entity specified by this expression.*

but this note:

> if the name of an object is parenthesised, it becomes an lvalue expression

lead me to the following question: what is the type of `a->x` if it is not a lvalue expression?

I don't even get why

```
decltype((a->x)) x4 = x3; // type of x4 is const double& (lvalue expression)
```

is evaluated as a `const&` only by the fact that it is considered as a lvalue expression, don't really see the link.

Comment: I don't really get the question. `decltype(a->x)` is `double`, because it is an unparenthesised class access (and `A::x` has declared type `double`). `decltype((a->x))` is not an unparenthesised class access, but is an _lvalue_. As a result the type is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `(a->x)` (which is `double const`, since `a` is a pointer to `const A`). What part of this do you not understand? (See `[dcl.type.simple]/4`)

Comment: hum ok, really find the way of putting this definition strange, but ok get the idea thanks.

Comment: I find [this](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2011/04/appearing-and-disappearing-consts-in-c/) helpful. Especially the **decltype** section. It also states that ".. when you ask decltype for the type of an expression that is not the name of a variable, it returns an lvalue reference **if** the type is an lvalue."

Comment: @user2218982: but `a->x` _is_ an lvalue, so that's highly misleading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> lead me to the following question what is the type of a->x if it is not a lvalue expression ?

You are simply confused.

> if the name of an object is parenthesised, it becomes an lvalue expression

That should be

> if the name of an object is parenthesized, it is handled different by decltype.

Both the parenthesized and nonparenthesized things are lvalue expressions. If you don't parenthesize, then decltype does not inspect the type of the expression, but the type used by the declaration that the name lookup found the name to refer to (for example, it could be `int&&` if name lookup resolves it to an rvalue reference variable, but the type of the expression is `int` and is an *lvalue*).

Answer (score 2):

The way to think about it is (IMHO) this:

```
decltype( a->x )
```

keeps/retrieves the information that `x` refers to a member variable, hence it gives you the declared type of the member variable. This is helpful because you couldn't extract that information if this would automatically turned into the next case:

```
decltype( (a->x) )
```

This is "just" an expression and therefore behaves like any other expression. It refers to whatever the expression *returns*, not what the expression *references*. The expression is an lvalue, it doesn't matter that it's a member variable. You *explicitly throw away a part of the information* that is available, expressing your intend of not being interested in what the object/member was declared as but only in the resulting type of the expression.

In other words: The first syntax gives you *more* information unless you *explicitly* decide you don't need them and use the second syntax.